# scheduling local notification with end date

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I want to schedule a local notification that alerts the user every day for the next year, but I haven't found a way to set the end date while scheduling them.

The user might not open the app every day.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to schedule 7 (or whatever the number was you needed) separate notifications with no repeat.

Comment: I just gave 'week' as an example...it might be an year or even more..i am looking for general solution..anyway thanks..

Comment: You need to be more specific then when formulating your question - asking something and then saying it was just an example after the fact really doesn't help people answer you. There is no way to do what you're looking for.